# Basic probability question on expectation value

Tags: probability

> You have a thirty-sided and I have a twenty-sided die. We roll both of
> them and whoever gets the higher roll wins. If we roll the same amount
> I win. The loser pays the dollar amount of the winning roll.
>
> What is the expected value of this game for you?

Could someone walk me through how to solve this?

Comment: What are the numbers on each die?

Comment: @angryavian 1-20 for the 20 sided die, 1-30 for the 30 sided die

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you know how expected value is defined? Can you write down what the definition of expected value is in this particular problem?

Answer (score -1):

The simple though tedious approach is to list all $600$ possible results of the rolls, add up the results, and divide by $600$. This would not be hard in a spreadsheet with copy down and copy right.  Any other approach is just a simpler way to get the same result.

An approach that is less work is to note that if I roll at least $21$ I have a guaranteed win.  These rolls contribute $20(\sum_{i=21}^{30}i)=20\cdot 10 \cdot \frac{51}2=5100$ to the sum.  The cases where we tie contribute $\sum_{i=1}^{20}-i=-210$ to the sum.  The cases where I roll $20$ or less and we don't tie contribute a net of $0$ because of the symmetry, so the expected value to me is $\frac {5100-210}{600}=8.15$